# Reproject, then clip or clip, then reproject?

Tags: coordinate-system, global

I have a fairly simple question. I have a global categorical land cover map that has no projected coordinate system (i.e. it uses the EPSG:4326 coordinate reference system with no projection). My study region encompasses an international regional geographical scope (for e.g. South Asia). I have to apply a projection to the data because I need the units of measurement to be in metres and not degrees.

My question is this; do I

1. apply a projection to the global map, then clip it to my region of interest (using a similarly re-projected vector country boundary layer)...or do I
2. clip it to my region of interest using an un-projected vector country boundary layer (i.e. EPSG:4326) and then reproject the resultant clipped raster to a suitable projection?

I am unsure which method is the proper method, can someone enlighten me? Or maybe they make no difference at all. But just thinking about it, it sounds like the first option is more sound (robust) as opposed to the second, primarily because my input data is a global dataset. Additionally, one reason I am thinking so is because I find it difficult to get appropriate projection systems that cover a regional landscape, but it is relatively easier to find multiple global projections.

Comment: Do neither, use gdalwarp to specify extent, dimension, projection and it does both as efficiently as possible

Answer (score 2):

I would first clip and then reproject.

The reason of this is that when reprojecting the resulting raster was made by re-calculating pixel values from the original and based in the distortion typically these new values are interpolated.

so going clip, then interpolate, it makes your final product a bit (emphasis on bit) cleaner

My untested theory is that the introduced error by the warping -if any- is canceled itself out as a whole, so it's really effect anything

Answer (score 0):

It depends what is important to you and what CRS the polygon you're clipping it with is in. If you're clipping it using a polygon in a projected system then I would recommend changing them both to the same CRS first.

When we go from a 3D world to a 2D world we have to effectively strech our map. This means that we lose either distance conformity - objects are not the correct distances from a central point, area conformity - polygons are not the correct area or angular conformity - north, east, south and west aren't exactly perpendicular any more.

I would suggest because you're interested in measurement that you want one that maintains distance/area as much as possible.

Comment: Thanks @DMADTim. To be specific. Both the global land cover map and the polygon are in EPSG:4326 (i.e. no projection). I require a projection that preserves area as much as possible. Some have recommended using Lambert equal-area cylindrical projection, which I believe is meant for projections on global-scale maps. Does this mean that if preserving area is important to me, and my data come in EPSG:4326, you would recommend clipping first, then reprojection?

Comment: Hi, so long as you're not using a really complicated grid system as your output e.g. the British OSGB36 that involves a very complex projection then I wouldn't say that it would make any difference in theory if they're both in the same grid (although there may be some intricate detail in the way that QGIS deals with these operations that I'm unaware of). If you're going to be working in the same CRS for the rest of the study then I would personally project at the start.